actions/setup-python@v3 failing with Error: Version 3.8 with arch x64 not found
Here's my workflow:
name: My First GitHub Actions

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted

    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: [3.8, 3.9]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install pytest

    - name: Run tests
      run: |
        cd src
        python -m pytest addition.py

But getting this error:
ubuntu@ip-172-31-16-175:~/actions-runner$ ./run.sh

√ Connected to GitHub

Current runner version: '2.316.1'
2024-05-18 18:20:12Z: Listening for Jobs
2024-05-18 18:20:15Z: Running job: build (3.8)
2024-05-18 18:20:23Z: Job build (3.8) completed with result: Failed
2024-05-18 18:20:24Z: Running job: build (3.9)
2024-05-18 18:20:28Z: Job build (3.9) completed with result: Canceled

Logs are showing this error:

Version 3.8 was not found in the local cache:
Error: Version 3.8 with arch x64 not found

Tried different Python versions but still getting the same error.
The list of all available versions can be found here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/actions/python-versions/main/versions-manifest.json
Can anyone please help me resolve these errors?

What happens if you use strings instead of floats to specify the version? python-version: ["3.8", "3.9"]

Still giving the same error.

I just noticed that you're not running these actions on github's runners; you're running them on a self-hosted environment. I haven't worked with self-hosted runners before, but I imagine this means you need to ensure the appropriate software packages have been installed in that environment.
